# How to disable numeric input datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I require some help with this issue. I want ONLY backspace and arrow keys working in the "Date1" field. I saw that once it becomes a "datepicker" field with the code below, numeric symbols and "/" is allowed. Can I disable this so that ONLY backspace and arrow keys work? Don't want people typing in random numbers..

```js
<script>
var dateToday = new Date();
$(function() {
    $( "#Date1" ).datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        minDate: dateToday
    });
});
</script>

<script>
var o = document.getElementById('Date1');
o.addEventListener( 'keydown', function( e ) {

    if( e.keyCode >= 37 && e.keyCode <= 40 ) {
        return; 
    }
    if( e.keyCode === 8 || e.keyCode === 58 ) {
        return; 
    }
    e.preventDefault( );
}, false );
</script>
```

```html
<input type="text" id="Date1" name="Date1">
```

Now, it's working as intended. I can't use all the letter keys on the keyboard i

Comment: You have HTML in JavaScript. It is syntax error. Why not use `<input type="date" />`?

Comment: It looks bad. The chrome date field looks very bad. It's working on my site so it's showing the date picker

Comment: Then use a datepicker plugin like BootStrap Date Picker or something?

Comment: I'm already using the jquery one. I added the src so it's using that.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you mark your input `readonly="true"` to disable input.

```
<input type="text" id="Date1" name="Date2" readonly="true">
```

This will serve the purpose.

## Update

As you stated that clearing the input field should be allowed. Please update your listener to this

```
o.addEventListener('keydown', function( e ) {    
   switch(e.keyCode){
       case (e.keyCode >= 37 && e.keyCode <= 40 ):
       case ( e.keyCode === 8 || e.keyCode === 58 ):
       case (e.keyCode >= 48 && e.keyCode <= 57);
           return;
       default:        
           console.log(e.keyCode); // do something for default
   }    
   e.preventDefault( );
```

}, false );

Comment: Thanks for your input. I've already done that, but the issue then is that there is no way the user can clear the date field. They should have the option to clear the field. I tried some code for adding a clear button to the popup datepicker, but it was not working. 

So if they choose a date and want to clear it, they can't.

Comment: Thank you I will give it a try.